# What's problems will have with below code on some devices?

Tags: c, linux, io

there is a code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char c;
    while( (c=getchar()) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

these code coming from chapter **I/O** of a book named **Unix Advanced Programming**,and it says the code will work not well in some machines,I tried the code in my mac,and it will work well,then anyone can tell me what's problem will have when run above code and why it occurs,thanks!

---

Update:
the code come from chapter I/O,so I think it will relevant to I/O operation.

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, so the code should have `int c;`, not `char c;`. `EOF` is defined as an integer `-1`. In some cases, if your system converts `EOF` to a `(char)(-1)` then the program will not distinguish between a character 255 and the EOF. Also, the program should have `exit(0)` or `return 0` at the end.

Comment: @lurker: wow. I tested this to be sure – I never realized `exit(x)` would make clang and gcc not issue the "missing `return x;` statement" for an `int main(..)`!

Comment: @lurker,you mean some system will converts EOF to (char)(-1) and the program won't distinguish between a character 255 and EOF,but when a char and an int are compared,will not they both be converted to int,not to char?

Comment: @FireSun not necessarily. If the header file has `#define EOF (-1)` then it's type isn't necessarily assumed to be `int` but could be determined by context. It's not a reliable programming assumption. This is why the book says, *...in some machines*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Storeing results of `getchar()` to variables having `char` type is a bad practice because `EOF` won't fit in `char` type. Using `int` is good.
- Not returning any values from main functon using `return` statement in old C may confuse some system such as online judge and treat the code as made Runtime Error. You should write `return 0;` at the end of function.

Comment: It is not an immediate problem if `char` is signed by default. But then you cannot distinguish EOF from an input byte `0xFF`!

Comment: And which machine won't work well when running this code on?

Comment: @FireSun The problem is not with the machine, it is with the compiler: If the compiler interpretes `char` as an unsigned datatype, the code will never exit from the loop because `EOF` is translated to `255` in the assignment to `char`. That has nothing to do with the hardware you are running on.